# Deleting select nodes from linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, free

I went through some articles that explain node deletion in a doubly linked list, but I am not able to understand why the following code is not working. Please suggest some solution(s).

I have two structs A and B. There is a linked list of structs A each of which contains a doubly linked list of B. I am trying to delete all those B structs from each of A that have Id less than a value. Here is how I am trying to do it.

```
typedef struct __B {
    int id;
    struct __B *next;
    struct __B *prev;
} B;

typedef struct __A {
    B *bList;
    struct __A *next;
} A;

void DeleteNodes(int value, A* AList) {
    while(AList != NULL) {
        B *BList = AList->bList;
        while(BList != NULL) {
            B *temp = BList;
            BList = BList->next;
            if(temp->id < value) {
                if(temp->prev == NULL) // delete first node
                    BList->prev = NULL;
                else {
                    temp->prev->next = BList;
                    temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                }
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp->prev = NULL;
                free(temp);
                temp = NULL;
            }
        }
        AList = AList->next;
    }
}
```

But when I traverse the AList and the corresponding BLists, the apparently deleted nodes are still present which is causing application crashes.
Please share some suggestions.

Comment: OT: The definition of `__B` is not allowed as per C11Draft/7.1.3: "*All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
underscore are always reserved for any use.*" (http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating `AList->bList` in your while loop, which is why it keeps pointing to the deleted items.
change your code to update `AList->blist`

```
void DeleteNodes(int value, A* AList) {
    while(AList != NULL) {
        B *BList = AList->bList;
        while(BList != NULL) {
            B *temp = BList;
            BList = BList->next;
            if(temp->id < value) {
                if(temp->prev == NULL) // delete first node
                    BList->prev = NULL;
                else {
                    temp->prev->next = BList;
                    temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                }
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp->prev = NULL;
                free(temp);
                temp = NULL;
            }
        }
        AList->bList = BList;
        AList = AList->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `AList->bList` that wasn't being updated, not `AList` itself. Your code is correct but the description is wrong.

Comment: I think that would make `AList->bList` NULL as `BList` is looped till it is NULL

Comment: @Nishant actually BaluRaman is right; you should set `AList->bList = BList` only when when the first node of the list is deleted (same place as `BList->prev = NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

You forget to set AList->bList to the new head of the list.

While you free() the content pointed to by `temp`, you also need to make sure that the pointer AList->bList points to the next item in the list. As you do not update it, it keeps pointing to the now free()d BList item and renders unspecified results.

Set `AList->bList` to `BList` before the `AList = AList->next;`